# c - detecting end of stream

Tags: c, inputstream

I am writing a **c** application and want to execute some external programs and parse the output similar to writing a script and using expect.

How do I set the timeout for executing a task?
How do I know that there is no more data to read from a stream, ie. it is waiting for input?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select() to check if there are bytes available to be read from the stream. If there are none, it's a good indication that the external program is not outputting things - it's either waiting for input or simply busy working. I don't think there's a generic way to tell the difference between the two states.

Comment: There is a way to tell. EOF is a zero-byte `read`. At EOF, `select` returns that the fd is readable, but `read` reads zero bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set the timeout for executing
>   a task?

Use `select()` and set a timeout. Invoke this before you call `recv()`.

> How do I know that there is no more
>   data to read from a stream, ie. it is
>   waiting for input?

This is trickier. You need to have some protocol so that the sending side can alert the receiving side that it is finished. The HTTP approach is just to close the socket on the sending side, which causes the receiving side's `recv()` to return zero bytes.

An alternative is that the sending side send a special character or character sequence. Another approach, depending on your application, you may have an exact number of bytes to transmit; this is rare though.

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually for parsing command-line output so I won't use recv.  The select() thing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on a POSIX compliant system:

You can timeout on the task's input stream by polling on it with a function like `select`. ([See this tutorial](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html)). the end of stream is detected using the `feof` function.

Comment: No, you're confusing low-level UNIX I/O (`open`, `close`, `read`, `write`, `socket`, `accept`, `poll`, `select`, etc.) with C standard library buffered I/O (`fopen`, `fclose`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fscanf`, `fprintf`, `feof`, etc.)  Notice that `feof` *only* works after `fread` or similar, and you really don't want to mix buffered and low-level I/O.